# Calling jasper report from jsp page with parmeter

Tags: java, html, asp.net, jsp, pdf

I am calling a index page which sends parameter to  page that runs a jasper report in PDF. but when i run the project i got the problem in generating PDF  says PDF format might not right or corrupted(Mozilla and IE11)

"index.jsp"

```
<form method="POST" action="ShowPdf.jsp">
    <input type="text" value="" id ="personId" name="personId">
    <input type="submit" value="show">  
</form>


int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("personId"));            
try
{
    Connection conn=null;
    //Connecting to the MySQL database

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/bd_hospital_nikdu", "root", "Admin123");

    File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("//reports//newReport2.jasper"));//your report_name.jasper file
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("personId",id);

    byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);

    //byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToHtmlFile(reportFile.getPath(),null, conn).getBytes();

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

    ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();

}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to improve your question to contain all the relevant info, so we can help you. Because as it is now, it's hard to deduce what your problem is without any code.

Comment: Please put code here so other can analyze your problem!

Comment: i have edited my question with code..plzz help me

Comment: Have you tried generating the PDF outside of the servlet environment, and outputting directly to a file to check if the file was also corrupted?

Comment: @DidierL  i can not understand  its a jasper report i am calling from jsp.it will gonna load in pdf

Comment: Try to run your code outside of your server, in a simple `main` method. Change `outStream` to be a `FileOutputStream`, and check if the result is correct.

Comment: plz put the codeblock what u have said so that i can clearly understand

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%@ page import="net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer" %>

<%@ page import="com.itextpdf.text.*"%>

<%@ page import="com.itextpdf.text.pdf.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>

<%

            /*Parametros para realizar la conexión*/

            Connection conexion;

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gae", "root", "");

            /*Establecemos la ruta del reporte*/

            File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("reportes//prueba1.jasper"));

            /* No enviamos parámetros porque nuestro reporte no los necesita asi que escriba cualquier cadena de texto ya que solo seguiremos el formato del método runReportToPdf*/

            Map parameters = new HashMap();

            parameters.put("cedula", "cedula");

            parameters.put("nombre", "nombre");

            /*Enviamos la ruta del reporte, los parámetros y la conexión(objeto Connection)*/

            byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conexion);

            /*Indicamos que la respuesta va a ser en formato PDF*/

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");

            response.setContentLength(bytes.length);

            ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length); /*Limpiamos y cerramos flujos de salida*/

            ouputStream.flush();

            ouputStream.close();

%>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <title>JSP Page</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    </body>

</html>
```